# Why is my join filter being applied to my entire query in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to build a tricky join across grains, with tableA being at a lower grain than tableB. In this example, I'm trying to accomplish the following results:

| tableA.id | tableA.fieldA | tableB.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 123 |
| 123 | 2 | null |
| 123 | 3 | null |
| 234 | 1 | 234 |
| 234 | 2 | null |
| 234 | 3 | null |

Here is my query to accomplish this:

```
Select
    *
from
    tableA

    left join tableB
    on tableB.id = tableA.id
    and tableA.fieldA = 1
```

Unfortunately, the "tableA.fieldA = 1" filter is acting as a filter on the entire query, and not just on the join, resulting in the following:

| tableA.id | tableA.fieldA | tableB.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 123 |
| 234 | 1 | 234 |

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to accomplish what I'm going for? Thanks!

Comment: I would guess the problem is that `tableB.id` is the presence of `NULL`.  This means the result of the compare of `id` columns is *indeterminate*.  Try putting in some logic, in the `ON` clause, specifically to handle the `NULL`.

Comment: unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue. I added the following lines to the join and where clauses: 
`tableB.id is not null and tableA.id is not null`
 Thank you for the idea, though!

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  In the SQL in the OP, there is no `where` clause.  If you added that logic to the `ON` *and* the `where`, you'd end up with much the same (erroneous) results that you give in the OP.  I did note also in the quoted SQL the equality is with `1`, not `10` as described in the text.  Is the post accurate?

Comment: good catch on the 10 vs 1. in my real data, it's a 10, even though it's always the first value( 10 > 20 > 30 etc). sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following code per your description and SQL on my Redshift and I get the answer you are looking for.

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  ID int,
  A int);
                   
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (123, 1)  ;  
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (123, 2)  ;
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (123, 3)  ;
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (234, 1)  ;
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (234, 2)  ;
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (234, 3)  ;

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  ID int);
  
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (123)  ;  
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (234)  ;

Select
    *
from
    table_A
    left join table_B
    on table_B.id = table_A.id
    and table_A.a = 1;
```

Results in:

```
id  a   id
123 1   123
123 2   NULL
123 3   NULL
234 1   234
234 2   NULL
234 3   NULL
```

I see a few possibilities at the moment - 1) your cluster is having issues / bug in the exact version you are running OR 2) your question write up doesn't represent the whole picture OR 3) my code doesn't represent your situation.

Does the code I provided above recreate the issue on your cluster?  If not can you provide the necessary ingredients (DDL, SQL) to recreate the issue?

Comment: your post got me thinking and i went back through my sql and found a dumb filter for tableB i left in, which filtered out the nulls. i appreciate you taking the time to build this. it really got me thinking in the right way to figure this out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That *should not* be happening like that; you should be getting all rows in `tableA` regardless of what the `ON` clause evaluates to.

But what you can do what you want with condition in the `select`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when a.fieldA = 1 then b.id end)
from tableA a left join
     tableB b
     on b.id = a.id ;
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to use that logic for every single calculation that I will need in the select. Can you elaborate on the "should not be happening" part? Is this potentially a bug?

Comment: @jeremy . . . A condition in the `on` clause should not be filtering rows from the table.